# single SSIS package with multiple package configurations

Tags: configuration, ssis

I have an SSIS package with 2 package configurations (Configuration1 and Configuration2) with configuration locations stored in 2 different enviornment variables. Which configuration has to be used is decided based on the value of a variable (`@type`) passed at run time.

That is , use Configuration1 when `@type ='override'` and
use Configuration2 when `@type ='overload'`.

How can I do this in SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SQL Execute Task which is executed optionally (based on the value of @type using Expression in Precedence Constraint) to update the value of Configuration in the "SSIS Configuration" table. You should in this case migrate your configuration from "Environment Variables" to SQL Server table.

Comment: Yes I did it for one client where we had to execute a procedure optionanly based one the value of one variable

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your approach then. My concern is that configurations are loaded before the package ever runs - [Understanding how Integration Services Applies Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671625.aspx) so there's now way, at least using the built-in/native configuration of SSIS to conditionally switch out a set of configurations for another. One could optionally execute an Execute SQL Task but that wouldn't cover all the configurable things the native addresses. Also doesn't cover connection managers as they may open connections when the package begins

Comment: What do you think about this:
` 
       -> setting @type 
       -> if @type = 'override' run (Execute SQL Task 1) 
          else if @type = 'overload' run (Execute SQL Task 2) 
       -> run (Execute SQL Task 3)
       -> run the remaining of the package
`

with:

(Execute SQL Task 1) = 
`UPDATE [config_table] 
   SET val = value_override
   WHERE filter = 'prop_n'`
(Execute SQL Task 2) = 
`UPDATE [config_table] 
   SET val = value_overload
   WHERE filter = 'prop_n'`
(Execute SQL Task 3) = 
`SELECT val WHERE filter = 'prop_n'` 

then affect the value to some variable and use it.

Comment: Thanks @Amine Chafai . In my scenario, the configuration approach cannot be migrated from "Environment Variables" to SQL Server table. Because the package is already in production and now I have to use the same package for one more scenario. So the Client will not allow to change the approach. Is there any other methods to do it without changing the "enviornment variable" approach?

Comment: If you have the permission to enable the stored procedure `xp_cmdshell`, you can use SQL Execute Task to retrieve one of the two environment variables into a variable then use it. Otherwise, You can also try to get the corresponding environment variable by using a script task that affect the value of environment variable to a package variable based on the input parameter @type.